# Do I need to implement LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks multiple times if I need to same data in other activity?

Tags: android, loader, android-loadermanager, android-loader

Do I need to implement LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks multiple times if I need to same data in other activity ?

If not then from where I can access data from onLoadFinished() when it was implemented 1st time

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. At least you need to register `OnLoadCompleteListener` in order to get updates from loader.

You can get the loader by passing the **same loader id** to  `getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID)`. In order to get data from the loader you need to register a listener   `getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID).registerListener(id, listerner)` in new activity and call `forceload` for reloading data.